# Azure ML pipeline fails with ImportError: cannot import name 'time_ns' error

Tags: python, pandas, azure

I am trying to run a ML pipeline in Azure, I use `pandarallel` module but the pipeline fails with below error.

```
    from pandarallel import pandarallel
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_76aa2eb12d27af119fdfef634eaaf565/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandarallel/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import pandarallel
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_76aa2eb12d27af119fdfef634eaaf565/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandarallel/core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .progress_bars import ProgressBarsType, get_progress_bars, progress_wrapper
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_76aa2eb12d27af119fdfef634eaaf565/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandarallel/progress_bars.py", line 8, in <module>
    from time import time_ns
ImportError: cannot import name 'time_ns'
```

In the dependencies yml file, I hard coded `pandarallel` version from `1.3.2` to `1.6.4` but all versions fail with either `time_ns` error or `ImportError: cannot import name 'PlasmaStoreFull'` or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipywidgets'`. Each version of `pandarallel` is giving such errors.

I am not using `time_ns` anywhere in my code. Could someone please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The time_ns() method on Python is used to fetch the time in nanoseconds. It's not an issue; the underlying error is caused by the module "**ipywidgets**".   The issue was caused by ipywidgets is not installed with IPython.

Please Install by using the below commands and re-run.

```
pip install ipywidgets

conda install ipywidgets
#Either command will resolve issue.
```

Here is the # [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-python-sdk): Create production ML pipelines with Python SDK v2 in a Jupyter notebook

with reference of [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256649/import-trouble-with-pyarrow-plasmastorefull)

try:

```
  # Pyarrow version > 0.14
    from pyarrow.plasma import PlasmaStoreFull as _PlasmaStoreFull
except ImportError:
    # Pyarrow version <= 0.14
    from pyarrow.lib import PlasmaStoreFull as _PlasmaStoreFull
```

see this [bugfix](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/commit/94e535a388c96825e68f7ce561cd8c9e5eb7b84d)

Comment: Even after installing ipywidgets, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Hi Karthik, please refer this solution it may helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256649/import-trouble-with-pyarrow-plasmastorefull

Comment: It's still throwing same error Swarna